# Ckeditor removes empty tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, fckeditor

There is a problem with CKEditor
when the user inserts empty tags:

(in HTML source mode)

```
<a href="fds" class="doIt"></a>
```

When he presses on the source and then back again, the tag 'A' is gone.
I made a little research, and I found that this happens since there is a very complicated function in ckeditor.js
that checks whether there is a value inside the element. If there's none the CKEditor drops the tag.

Comment: Have you tried removing the function?

Comment: This creates havoc with my code, since some of my so-called empty div's actually have background-images, but CKEditor doesn't care, and removes them nonetheless...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but in CKEDITOR 4.x you can do:

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.ElementHere = 0;
```

Replace ElementHere with whatever tag you want.
Like allowing empty i tags for icons:

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.i = 0;
```

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: This worked like a charm, I applied it on span elements.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't affect anything try adding `&nbsp;` in your A tag.  ckeditor validates, sanitizes, and cleans html.  Obviously it doesn't like empty anchor tags.

Comment: yes, but i have some solution that he will adding automatically, and not in manual way, this is not help me

Comment: I need some solution that  will add automatically, and not in manual way, this is not help me

Comment: Not a particularly helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this specific problem i ran into with the  tag

The original answer i got from [CKEditor strips <i> Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250404/ckeditor-strips-i-tag/18254082#18254082)

The fix or tweak (you name it) for it is to set the following into the ckeditors config.js:

```
// ALLOW <i></i>
config.protectedSource.push( /<i[\s\S]*?\>/g ); //allows beginning <i> tag
config.protectedSource.push( /<\/i[\s\S]*?\>/g ); //allows ending </i> tag
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this line into your config.js file:

```
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: No, that's a new setting introduced in 4.1 to disable the ACF, but that's not related to empty tags.

Comment: This does not help mate, We are specifically talking about empty divs here not ckeditor automatic content filtering, which would have already been disabled.