# CKEditor strips <i> Tag

Tags: tags, ckeditor, fckeditor

I'm trying to find a solution to avoid CKEditor, but also the older FCKeditor strips out any
`<i>` tag from previously inserted content to the db.

**Case:**

I insert html content to the db, some content contain the `<i>` elements.
I do this with the CKEditor.
Everything works perfect and the content shows up on the webpage.
But when i want to edit the previously inserted content,  the `<i>` elements are missing.

*In my specific case i use:*

```
<i class="fa-icon-fullscreen fa-icon-xxlarge main-color"></i>
```

Of course if i disable the editor, the content shows up just fine in the textarea.

Comment: There is another SO question about this where a guy shows a broad method to allow empty tags: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25016231/2418655

Comment: I eliminated the problem by removing CKEditor (which I like a lot) from the project and using codemirror/jsbeautify without a WYSIWYG. May not be an option for most.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I found the solution for this specific problem i ran into with the `<i>` tag

The original answer i got from [drupal forum](https://drupal.org/node/1908696)

The fix or tweak (you name it) for it is to set the following into the ckeditors config.js:

```
// ALLOW <i></i>
config.protectedSource.push(/<i[^>]*><\/i>/g);
```

*Thanks to **Spasticdonkey** for pointing me to the link.*

Comment: no, you cant see the icons in the wysiwyg area.But when you look in the Source of the wysiwyg editor, you will see the <i>.

Comment: I have scoured the Net, and this is the only thing that will work. Now I must modify it to keep empty divs and others.

Comment: in version 2.6.3 i add FCKConfig.ProtectedSource.Add(/<i[^>]*><\/i>/g); and this  is working

Comment: after making this change I try to minify it but  I get errors caused by this line

Answer (score 75):

When the protectedSource solution is used, `i` tags are no longer stripped, but `img` tags stop showing up in the WYSIWIG mode of CKEditor (I'm using 4.3.1). The solution that worked better for me is to disable removing empty `i` tags using `CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty`

For example, I added the following to the config.js

```
// allow i tags to be empty (for font awesome)
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['i'] = false;
```

Note: This should be placed outside the `CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )` function.

Comment: This seems like the most sensible way to me. Shame answers added after the fact don't get much recognition.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44417887/how-to-make-ckeditor-stop-removing-empty-divs/52969977#52969977

Comment: I've bundled up the various fixes in [this related Drupal issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor/issues/1908696#comment-13931928). There are 2 problems fixed by this solution: HTML filtering not permitting `<i>` tags at all, and ACF cleaning them up anyway by default.

Answer (score 26):

Here is what works for me

add the 3 lines of code below in the same order in the drupal ckeditor profile setting
admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full

ADVANCED OPTIONS >> Custom JavaScript configuration

```css
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.extraAllowedContent = 'p(*)[*]{*};div(*)[*]{*};li(*)[*]{*};ul(*)[*]{*}';
    CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.i = 0;
```

First line is pretty much turning off the advanced filtering

Second line is allowing ALL class (*), any style {*} and any attribute [*] for the p,div, li and ul.

The last line is for the empty  tag...this line works with images...I have found that if you use 
config.protectedSource.push(/]*></i>/g);
it strips out the  tag while editing.

Comment: Very nice @Alauddin. I tried everything on this page and elsewhere. Your solution works for me. Much appreciated! Question (minor detail): is there a way to preserve the indentation of the HTML source?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the only working solution on Drupal!

Answer (score 5):

for 4.3 version ckeditor

in config.js (after config section) paste

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['b'] = false;
```

and write widget with code

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'bwcaret', {
requires: ['widget'/*, 'richcombo'*/],

icons: 'bwcaret',

init: function( editor ) {

    editor.widgets.add( 'bwcaret', {

        button: 'Create a caret',

        template: '<b class="caret"></b>',


        allowedContent: 'b(!caret)',

        requiredContent: 'b(!caret)',

        upcast: function( element ) {
            return element.name == 'b' && element.hasClass( 'caret' );
        },

    });
}
```

});

Comment: impossible, widgets were introduced in 4.3

Answer (score 3):

i found a permanent solution for it.actually what happened ckeditor removing only blank tag.whatever the tag is, may b `<i>` tag or `<span>` tag

if you are using any icon like font-awesome,maeterlize icon etc ...
you can stop it by using below code in your `config.js` file

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.span = false; 
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.i = false;
```

if you are using more blank tag then you need to add the tag name after `$removeEmpty`

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible problems:

- Read about [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter). CKEditor is removing elements which are not allowed, but you can extend filter's rules.
- However, if the problem is that CKEditor removes empty `<i>` elements, then you need to find other way of using it. CKEditor is not a WYSIWYG website builder. It is a document editor, so the loaded content must have a meaning. Empty inline element does not have any meaning, therefore it is removed, because otherwise editor would not know what to do with it.

  One of the possible solutions in the (near) future, will be to use [Widgets system](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9764), to handle those empty elements. But for now I advice you to check the [CKEDITOR.htmlDataProcessor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlDataProcessor) and [short guide](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Data_Processor) how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

CKEditor 4 removes emtpy tags, so here you can do trick without changing any config settings.

**Replace**

```
<i class="fa-icon-fullscreen fa-icon-xxlarge main-color"></i>
```

**With**

```
<i class="fa-icon-fullscreen fa-icon-xxlarge main-color">&nbsp;</i>
```

Now `<i></i>` tag have content i.e. **`&nbsp;`** so CKEditor will not remove that tag.