# Losing formatting when switching between Source and WYSIWYG in CKEditor 4.2

Tags: ckeditor, strip-tags

I am using CKEditor version 4.2.2 Drupal module.
When I toggle the 'Source' button (swithing between Plain Text and Rich Text) I end up losing some tags.
It seems that the CKEditor rewrites the HTML code.
I did quite a bit of search so far about this and I added in the "Custom JavaScript configuration"
(in the configuration section of the CKEditor module), this line of code:

`config.allowedContent = true;`

With the above code I had partial success, now it leaves alone more tags but for the following code:

`<h2>404<i class="icon-file"></i></h2>`

CKEditor rewrites it as:

`<h2>404</h2>`

It removes the empty i tags. The i tag above is for font icons.

How can I prevent CKEditor from rewriting the Markup when switching between Source View and WYSIWYG view?

The problem I have is that multiple users edit the same document and some use WYSIWYG editor while others use the Plain text view. And you see how things get messy.

Thanks.

Comment: The tag `<i>` already has a historical semantic meaning as "italic". There's no real point in using it for an icon. Use some other tag and it'll be nicer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CKeditor strips <i> Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250404/ckeditor-strips-i-tag)

Answer (score 0):

The tag `<i>` already has a historical semantic meaning as italic text. There's no real point in using it for an icon. Use some other tag and it'll be easier.

CKE automatically strips empty `<i>`, `<b>`, `<span>` and such. You can go around this, see this question: [CKEditor strips <i> Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250404/ckeditor-strips-i-tag) But I don't recommend it. Wouldn't some other approach be nicer and more natural, like using an `<img>`? Or maybe even better, adding a class directly to the H2 element and using some CSS/JS to get the desired result?

For the BOFH option, teach your users to input `&nbsp;` into the element like this: `<i>&nbps;</i>` - and the element will stay in place. Horrible option, don't do it.

*Also related: [ckeditor removing empty span automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261198/ckeditor-removing-empty-span-automatically)*

Comment: Thanks Nenotlep for directing me to the right answer. To recap: I am using Font-Awesome, and I want to prevent the CKEditor 4.2 from removing the <i></i> tag. Here is the original solution: https://drupal.org/node/1908696    It works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;` in ckeditor config file. This option tells CKeditor to not fill empty tags with `&nbsp;`. But it'll probably force ckeditor to not affect empty tags at all.