# ckeditor 5 removes empty tags - and I don't want it to

Tags: tags, font-awesome, ckeditor5

I'm using FA to render icons, eg

`<i class="fa-thin fa-table-cells"></i>`

and ckeditor 5 removes them.

Any ideas how to prevent this behaviour?

NB - I'm using ckeditor v5. I've tried:

```
htmlSupport: {  
allow: [
    { name: /<i[^>]*><\/i>/g },
    { name: "i", classes: ["fa-thin", "fa-regular", "fa-light", "fa-solid", "fa-brands"] }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23983357/128761) work for you? This answer use CK 4. I can see the [document](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dtd.html#property-S-removeEmpty) in V4 but not in V5. Not sure that it still work.

Comment: Found the same [issue](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/9888) on GitHub.

Comment: @vee not in V5. And I've seen the GitHub issue: I was hoping for a workaround in the meantime... Thanks, though!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250404/ckeditor-strips-i-tag

Comment: This is not a duplicate as the method is completely different than Ckeditor 4. I've been looking for a solution for hours without success.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<span>` instead of `<i>`. Fontawesome support any inline tag, and CKEditor 5 in Drupal 10 (tryed in 10.1.6) keeps empty `<span>` tags in text.

So `<span class="far fa-copyright"></span>` does the trick.

**P.S.**:

- `<span>` should be added to '*Source Editing*' -> '*Manually editable HTML tags*' setting of CKEditor for text format: [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/ZL861zWQuY95)
- '*Correct faulty and chopped off HTML*' checkbox should be unset for text format