# CKEDITOR stripping the anchor tag inside a button

Tags: html, ckeditor, strip

I have a piece of html code like this

```
<button class="login_btn"><a href="#">Login</a></button>
```

But when I apply CKEDITOR inline editor, it turns to

```
<button class="login_btn">Login</button>
```

I tried using

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

and

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'button(*){*};a(*){*};';
```

but the issue still persists. I do not want anything to be stripped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CKEditor is stripping `<a>` from `<button>` because a `<button>` **cannot contain** an `<a>` element. Check your HTML with the [HTML validator](http://html5.validator.nu/).

From the [html5 button spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element):

> there must be no [interactive content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) descendant.

And the [interactive content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) page lists the anchor tag `<a>` as the first example.

Comment: It doesn't allow `<div>` inside `<a>`, even though the validator validates that.

Answer (score 2):

If you need force fix it you can add a configuration (you can just add a line to the end of the config.js inside **ckeditor** folder):

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.button.a = 1;
```

It means: you allow in your editor tag `<a>` inside tag `<button>`. It works for me.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using another HTML Editor, like [CoffeCup](http://www.coffeecup.com/free-editor/) or [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)? I think it's just a problem with your Editor. I already tried your code and it works fine.

Comment: I am talking here about WYSIWYG editor. The editor which could be embedded into a web page. Did u try my code in CKeditor?

Comment: I can't help but maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250404/ckeditor-strips-i-tag) can help you.