# How to allow all html tags and attributes with CKeditor?

Tags: javascript, regex, ckeditor

I'm trying to allow all html tags

```
<div> <p> <span> <i> /* etc */
```

and html attributes like below (class, id) for eg:

```
<div id="foo" class="bar" style="z-index:1;">SOME COOL CONTENT HERE</div>
```

in ckeditor.

I found something like in docs.ckeditor.com

```
config.allowedContent = {
    $1: {
        // Use the ability to specify elements as an object.
        elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
        attributes: true,
        styles: true,
        classes: true
    }
};
config.disallowedContent = 'script; *[on*]';
```

and added it to `config.js` in ckeditor's root folder. But nothing changed. When i'm trying to add some html tags on ckeditor's source code block it's erasing all of html contents.

What am i missing?
Thanks in advance.

**Version: ## CKEditor 4.4.7**

---

**EDIT & UPDATE:**

After @Eelke and @Necreaux answers i added `allowedContent = true` in my config.js. Now basic html elements such `<div> <span> <h3>` working perfectly. But ckeditor still striping `<i>` tags.

Completely Config JS

```
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) { 
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.removeFormatAttributes = '';
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For complete reference see:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'others' },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'about' }
    ];

    // Remove some buttons provided by the standard plugins, which are
    // not needed in the Standard(s) toolbar.
    config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';

    // Set the most common block elements.
    config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre;';

    // Simplify the dialog windows.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
};
```

Comment: Please post your FULL config.js. And specify which version of CKEditor you are using.

Comment: Is it completely stripping out the <i> tags or is it changing them to something else?

Comment: @Necreaux it's completely stripping `<i>` tags.

Comment: This is a different question why empty inline elements are removed. The base of this question is a DUP of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div

Comment: @Reinmar i'm not sure what is different question but i asked why ckeditor stripping html elements and attributes.

Comment: @Reinmar btw; i found answer in that question's answer. Thank you for pointing it up (:

Comment: What I meant is that there are two reasons. One - why disallowed elements are removed (regardless of their content). Second - why inline empty elements are removed (regardless of whether they are allowed).

Comment: Can you please change your comment to answer i can accept it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first thing is why some elements, attributes, styles and classes are removed regardless of their content. This is caused by the [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf). See this question for more details about how to change its settings:  [CKEditor automatically strips classes from div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div)

Another thing is why empty inline elements are removed regardless of whether they are allowed or not. This question was also asked already - see [CKEditor strips <i> Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250404/ckeditor-strips-i-tag) - note there's more that one good answer there.

Comment: CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' ).config.allowedContent = true;

Answer (score 17):

If everything is allowed, you can use `allowedContent = true`

Comment: i tried it also. It's allowing all html elements expect `<i></i>` and some others.

Comment: Where ? Can you be more specific please ?

Comment: i am using this but it don't let me put <label> tag

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried the following?

```
config.allowedContent = true;
config.removeFormatAttributes = '';
```

Comment: i tried it now and nothing changed. Still erasing `<i>` tag. Thx for effort.

Comment: Also add config.removeFormatTags = '';

Comment: Is it at a point where it translates them to "em"? That's the behavior I get, I'm not sure why you have this behavior.

Comment: Btw `<em>` is stripping too.

Comment: I'm using 4.4.3 and I can't replicate any of this. Have you tried nuking out your entire custom config settings and see if that does it. One of those other options could be doing it. Also, what install type do you have?

Comment: I'm using standart package. I will try to comment other custom settings in config.js if they are blocking some rules.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried this ?

```
<script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'text-area-id' );
        CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

these are the tags CKEditor 4 removes when empty:

abbr, acronym, b, bdi, bdo, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, i, ins, label, kbd, mark, meter, output, q, ruby, s, samp, small, span, strike, strong, sub, sup, time, tt, u, var

to allow all empty tags - try to add this to the config.js :

```
for(var tag in CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty){
    CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty[tag] = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

CKEditor 4 removes emtpy tags, so here you can do trick without changing any config settings.

**Replace**

```
<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
```

**With**

```
<i class="fas fa-arrow-right">&nbsp;</i>
```

Now `<i></i>` tag have content i.e. **`&nbsp;`** so CKEditor will not remove that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for CKEditor 4.

Don't go for old version of CKEditor and this type of config.

Just add   `config.allowedContent = true;` in your configuration. 
It will allows all tags.