# Why CKEditor ignores empty div or is it something else?

Tags: string, ckeditor, code-cleanup, strip-tags

I have written a plugin that adds bootstrap grid into the editor.However it seems that CKEditor deletes the whole wrapping col div when there is no content inside it.

Plugin on github: https://github.com/radko26/CKEditor_layoutmanagerPlugin/tree/master/layoutmanager

This is what is default inside the dom.When i delete the 'content', the editor removes the wrapping div-layout-column .

```
<div class="container-fluid layout-container">
  <div class="row  layout-row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 layout-column">   
        <p>content</p>
     </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 layout-column">
       <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 layout-column">  
      <p>content</p>   
    </div>
 </div>
```

I read through this documentation and althought the div element is not stripped on default, i added

```
 config.protectedSource.push(/<div[^>]><\/div>/g);
 CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['div'] = false;
```

inside the config.js.

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dtd

I have thought about a workaround: to listen for editor change when layout-column will be with no data,(i must think more about that part), and insert blank space to prevent the editor from removing it, but i was wondering if any event is fired when the editor removes the div or is there easier way to solve my problem.

I tried the solutions suggested but none of them seems to solve the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CKEditor strips <i> Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250404/ckeditor-strips-i-tag) Note that the question is a little different but some of the answers/solutions apply.

Comment: I had a look on it but it could not solve the problem.I have tried to wrap into widget but it also removed the div with style.

Comment: Look at the last comment on there by @alauddin. Have you tried that approach?

Comment: Yup, i tried but nothing happens.