# CKEDITOR : Remove last undo from stack CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

My Question is

How to remove the last undoing from undoing stack?

I'm Doing something in CKEditor.And I'm using

```
editor.fire('lockSnapshot');
```

and

```
editor.fire('unlockSnapshot');
```

My **Original** HTML content is

[image: Original TEXT]

After **Change** Something(put del/ins tag using MY CODE)

[image: After Changes Made]

And I add something in the editor and **doing undo** it will change like this.

[image: Wrong Output]

And this is my code.

```
editor.fire('lockSnapshot');
$(currentSpanNode).after('<ins class="ice-ins ice-cts">' + spanInnerText + '</ins>');
$(currentSpanNode).after('<del class="ice-del ice-cts">' + spanOuterHTML + '</del>');
$(currentSpanNode).remove();
editor.fire('unlockSnapshot');
```

'**currentSpanNode**' have a particular span Node.

I want to know..

Is there any possible way to ***Remove/Update*** Stack of undo?

If possible tell me the way.

Please, anyone get me out of this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407895/how-to-discard-only-the-last-element-of-ckeditor-undo-stack/29408755

Comment: I already try this.It shouldn't work at all.

Comment: I feel your pain... is there any chance you found out about a solution?

Comment: oh.. the lockSnapshot event actually works pretty well, nvm then...