# How to remove empty tag from CKeditor

Tags: ckeditor

How do I remove an empty tag from CKeditor? I've tried:

```
Regex.Replace(clean, "(<[/a-zA-Z]+?)([^>]*?)(>)", "$1$3");

Regex.Replace(input, @"<([^>/][^>]*)>((&nbsp;)*|\s*)</\1>", String.Empty);

config.allowedContent = true;

config.removeFormatAttributes = '';
```

in config.js of ckeditor but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds similar like this question here: [CKEditor strips <i> Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250404/ckeditor-strips-i-tag)

It should be possible to define if the tags are allowed to be empty or not:

```
// allow i tags to be empty (for font awesome)
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['i'] = false
```

If you would allow disallow it for every tag, they should get removed.

I only played with the 'i' tag case in the past. But I believe it is possible with all other tags as well.

Comment: thank you for your response but this is not working in my project

Comment: Is there a JSFiddle or something of what you are trying to do?