# CKEditor Configuration, why it remove my html code?

Tags: html, ckeditor

my ckeditor has this configuration:
config.allowedContent = true;

If I insert this code into my editor:

```
<a href="#" class="circle large border"> <span class="icojam_anchor"></span> </a>
```

this is a simple link with span content

The script will be remove. Why? I need to disable the HTML correction. Is it possible?

Thanks
Luca

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable removing empty span tags using `CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty`

For example, adding the following to the config.js

```
// allow span tags to be empty
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.span = 0;`

//The following allows i tags to be empty
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['i'] = false
```

Source: [CKEditor strips <i> Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250404/ckeditor-strips-i-tag)