# how to make ckeditor stop removing empty divs

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

There are similar questions to this here on stackoverflow, but the answers in those questions do not work for me, so please don't flag this as a duplicate.

In my cms, I want people to be able to add content pages that are SPA (Single Page Applications). It is very common for these kinds of apps to have nothing but a div with some attributes and javascript is used to load the app into the div. So I want users to be able to create content that consists only of an empty div with some attributes like this:

```
<div data-cscal-eventsource="default" data-cscal-height="550" id="eventCal" class="cs-eventcal"></div>
```

However ckeditor (I'm using version 4.6.2 at the moment) always removes the empty div. From googling and finding similar questions here I have tried various things in config:

```
allowedContent : true
```

is supposed to turn off all filtering but it still gets removed.

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['div'] = false;
```

is also found in some answers but does not work for me.

before setting allowedContent to true I tried various things with extraAllowedContent like this:

```
extraAllowedContent: 'div(*){*}[*]; ol li span a(*){*}[*]'
```

If the div has some text it works like this for example:

```
<div data-cscal-eventsource="default" data-cscal-height="550" id="eventCal" class="cs-eventcal">hello</div>
```

but I don't want that text and using a nbsp doesn't work either.

How can I make CKEditor leave my empty div alone? My div is the only content in the editor, the script and css for my SPA is added from outside the editor. I just need to be able to add the div without it being removed. I am trying to add the div using the sourcedialog.

I do not want to modify the ckeditor source code to solve this.

My complete code for clarity is like this, you can see in comments some of the things I have tried:

```
(function ($) {

var xsrfToken = $('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]:first').val();
var dfUrl = $("#editorconfig").data("dropfileuploadurl") || '/filemanager/upload';
var fbUrl = $("#editorconfig").data("filebrowserurl") || '/filemanager/filedialog?type=file';
var ibUrl = $("#editorconfig").data("imagebrowseurl") || '/filemanager/filedialog?type=image';
var editorId = $("#editorconfig").data("editorid") || 'foo';
var datepickerid = $("#editorconfig").data("datepickerid") || 'foo';
var usingCdn = $("#editorconfig").data("usingcdn");

var editorConfig = {
    toolbar: [['Sourcedialog', 'Maximize'],
['SelectAll', 'RemoveFormat', 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Print'],
['Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'Find', 'Replace', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'Strike', 'Superscript'],
    '/',
    ['Blockquote', 'Format'], ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList'],
['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'],
['Image', 'oembed', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar','CodeSnippet']],
    extraPlugins:'oembed,cloudscribe-filedrop,sourcedialog,codesnippet',
    removePlugins: 'scayt,wsc',
    format_tags: 'p;h1;h2;h3;h4;pre;address;div',
    dropFileUploadUrl: dfUrl,
    dropFileXsrfToken:xsrfToken,
    linkWebSizeToOriginal:true,
    forcePasteAsPlainText:true,
    filebrowserWindowHeight:'70%',
    filebrowserWindowWidth:'80%',
    filebrowserBrowseUrl:fbUrl,
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: ibUrl,
    allowedContent : true, //temporary trying to disable filtering
    extraAllowedContent: 'div(*){*}[*]; ol li span a(*){*}[*]', // allow all classes and attributes for these tags
    fillEmptyBlocks: false
};

if (usingCdn === true) {
    //alert('using cdn');
    CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('widget', '/ckjs/plugins/widget/', 'plugin.js');
    CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('widgetselection', '/ckjs/plugins/widgetselection/', 'plugin.js');
    CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('lineutils', '/ckjs/plugins/lineutils/', 'plugin.js');
    CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('oembed', '/ckjs/plugins/oembed/', 'plugin.js');
    CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('cloudscribe-filedrop', '/ckjs/plugins/cloudscribe-filedrop/', 'plugin.js');

}

//editorConfig.protectedSource.push(/<div[^>]*><\/div>/g);
//CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['div'] = false;

//$.each(CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty, function (i, value) {
//    CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty[i] = 0;
//});

var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(editorId, editorConfig);

ck.on('instanceCreated', function (ev) {
    CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['div'] = false;
});

var userLocale = $('#' + datepickerid).data("locale");
$('#' + datepickerid).datetimepicker({
    debug: false,
    widgetPositioning: { horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'bottom' },
    keepOpen: true,
    allowInputToggle: true,
    locale: userLocale
});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I have the same issue and none of the answers I found resolves it.

Comment: No I didn't. I made an option to disable the editor per page in my cms so users could just use a plain textarea to put in an empty div for a SPA

Answer (score 2):

`config.basicEntities = false; //in your cke.editor config js file`

Works for me.

**UPDATE**

Try this and see if it works, but i can have empty divs no problem.

```
for (var tag in CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty) {
    CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty[tag] = false;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Also try this, I have this in my config that does not remove empty div's

`config.htmlEncodeOutput = false;`

Comment: Also something else to try.

Comment: thanks again but not working for me with htmlEncodeOutput = false. I also already tried setting remove empty tag to false for div and for all tags, it didn't solve the problem for me

Comment: Seems like something isn't right, this is my config and I just tested and it works ;)

Comment: Honestly not even sure doesn't say anywhere.

Comment: Sorry just found it randomly in a random file - they do not document well. Anyways, it looks like im on version 3.6.3

Comment: Revision # 7474

Comment: Can you verify that other config changes work? Maybe something wrong with your config not working?

Comment: yes config is working, ie plugins, toolbar setup all change if I change them, it is definitely using my config

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250404/ckeditor-strips-i-tag

Answer (score 2):

Pretty tricky - in my case I needed to set

```
config.ignoreEmptyParagraph = false;
```

to finally having the DIV shown ... beside

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.div = 0
```

and having DIVS allowed at all ...

Comment: config.ignoreEmptyParagraph = false; Only this work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's late but I reply here for any reference.
We can set in config.js of CKEditor
config.extraAllowedContent = 'div style;*id';

Note: I'm using CKEditor 4

Answer (score 0):

In CKEditor, you can have a [configuration file](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_configuration.html).

And you can add the [custom config with the options here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-customConfig).