# while saving data to a database some of html parts are being lost

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Here is my model:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title      = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    slug       = models.SlugField()
    priority   = models.IntegerField()
    body       = RichTextUploadingField()
    author     = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status     = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='published'
```

The problem is when I save the record, some of the HTML elements are escaped. For example,I cannot save `<I class="icofont-check-circled"></i>`. Could you help me

Comment: Can you share more details please? Where do you save data?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The problem was not about escaping in Django framework but on CKEditor configuration. I just added     `config.protectedSource.push(/<i[^>]*><\/i>/g);`to CKEditor config file. It solved my issue.

The complete answer is here: [CKEditor strips <i> Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250404/ckeditor-strips-i-tag)