# CKeditor doesnt allow html icon tags

Tags: html, ckeditor

If i write some html in my web editor, and i copy this html into ckeditor in html view, after saving the content, the editor always delete html and font awesome ikons.

From this:

```
<a class="document_to_link" href="/documents/gipszkarton-falak.pdf" target="_blank" title="Gipszkarton válaszfalak">Katal&oacute;gus megnyit&aacute;sa <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
```

Will be this after saving:

```
<a class="document_to_link" href="/documents/gipszkarton-falak.pdf" target="_blank" title="Gipszkarton válaszfalak">Katal&oacute;gus megnyit&aacute;sa</a>
```

How can i allow `<i>` html tags?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250404/ckeditor-strips-i-tag

Comment: No, beacuse if i copy each code to my site, i get unpexpected token error.